# Firebase auth works, but Ui is blinking username to undefined in svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

1. It seems working shortly
2. The problem is blinking screen, when i do form action, ui shows email very shortly, but change to undefined

- +page.svelte

```html
<div>
    <div>
        {$fbUser?.email}
    </div>
    {#if !$fbUser}
        <a href="/auth">go auth</a>
    {/if}
</div>
```

- +page.server.ts

```js
export const actions: Actions = {
    register: async ({ request }) => {
        const data = await request.formData();
        const email = String(data.get('email'));
        const password = String(data.get('password'));
        try {
            await fbUser.createUser({ email, password });
        } catch (e) {
            if (e instanceof FirebaseError) {
                return fail(409, {
                    failed: true,
                    error: e.message
                });
            }
        }
        throw redirect(307, "/home")
    },
```

- writable store

```js
const userWritable = writable<User | null>(fb_auth.currentUser);

function authStore() {
    const { set, subscribe, update } = userWritable;

    const changes = () => onAuthStateChanged(fb_auth, (u) => {
        if (u) set(u)
        else update((curr) => curr = u)
    })

    return {
        subscribe,
        createUser: async (user: Register) => {
            await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(fb_auth, user.email, user.password);
            changes()
        },
```

I tried installing onAuthStateChanged in +page.svelte instead of store
using load function for onAuthStateChanged ...
but all result are same.
email shows very shortly after that it is changed to undefined.
seems serverside(firebase) works, but i think im missing something on ui concepts

Comment: Possibly you are stacking up `onAuthStateChanged` handlers. The method itself returns an `unsubscribe` function that should be called if you're creating a new user, else you're still getting updates for both and as the latter is now logged out, it would be updating your state too.

Comment: @Gavin 1. i removed all unsub(changes() stacks) functions follwing your advices and onAuthStateChanged func is moved in load function and linked again my store. 2. just install setter in store. After form submitted and redirect, but results are same. my auth information(with JSON.Strinfy) is shown in UI very shortly but immediately changed undefined.

Comment: So if you see the email immediatley on page load, then it disappears, then that means the SSR succeeded in getting the email, but it gets overridden by onAuthStateChanged. Also, I belive you should just be using `set(u)` instead of `update((curr) => curr = u)`. Changing what `curr` is referencing might break store functionality. `update` should return something new.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an await block surround your div in +page.svelte

```
{#await fbUser}
<div>
    <div>
        {$fbUser?.email}
    </div>
    {#if !$fbUser}
        <a href="/auth">go auth</a>
    {/if}
</div>
{/await}
```